# php conditional statement: not equal to operator

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to do the following with **wordpress**:

"If is **NOT** page 92, **OR** page parent is **NOT** 92."

Here is what I have:

`<?php if (!is_page(92) || $post->post_parent !== 92) { echo $foo; } ?>`

If I use one or the other as condition, it works; When I add the second condition, it breaks.

Any help would be well appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: have you checked the values of both, to ensure they are not the same value?

Comment: Just to clarify language ambiguity, you do mean "if _either_ the page is not 92 or if parent is not 92", and not "if _neither_ page _nor_ parent are 92," right? (For the latter you'd need `&&` instead of `||`.)

Comment: @Cyclone My intended condition does not filter. (the variable foo, displays on the pages I want to exclude it from)

Comment: @Wiseguy That's correct. (first statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably in using || instead of &&.

You want it to echo if you are not on page 92 **AND** you are not in a subpage of page 92.

Let's say you're on page 92, then your current code does this:

`if (false || true)`

because 92 is not a parent of page 92.  Thus, since one condition is true, it triggers.

If you're on a subpage of 92, then it's the opposite:

`if (true || false)`

If you're on a page that isn't 92 or a subpage of 92, then you get:

`if (true || true)`

So, it will always trigger, regardless of what page your on, because || requires only a single true statement for the entire condition to be true.

Hence, change your code to

`<?php if (!is_page(92) && $post->post_parent !== 92) { echo $foo; } ?>`

Which gives a logical run down like:

Page 92:

`if(false && true) //false, won't trigger`

Subpage of 92:

`if(true && false) //false, won't trigger`

Some unrelated page:

`if(true && true) //true, will trigger`

Comment: ahhhhh, yes. You are right! I forgot that if one condition was met, condition is triggered..

Comment: Oh. That's what I thought I had clarified in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional equals sign in your statement. The operator !== is for boolean checks. Since post_parent will automatically resolve to "true" since it has a value, it will always echo "foo". Change it to the following.

```
<?php if (!is_page(92) || $post->post_parent != 92) { echo $foo; } ?>
```

Comment: Not true.  !== is for all data types.  Of course, it could be his problem, if `$post->post_parent` returns a string and not an int, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Agreed - I forgot that variables with values present will auto-resolve to "true".

Comment: No, no, no.  !== checks for equivalency and type.  `"92" !== 92` is true because one is a string and the other is an int.  `92 !== 92` is false because they are both ints and equivalent to one another.  `"92" != 92` is false, because it doesn't check type and will type juggle to see if they are equivalent.

Comment: Then I'm curious as to the behavior of the is_page() function and the returned result from there. It may be what is causing your conditional to fail.

Answer (score 0):

It's only != not !==, only one equal

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php 'Not identical'
I don't think this is the problem here.

Comment: It can be !== too.  !== is the literal type checking one.