# jplayer and jquery, adding a function

Tags: jquery, javascript, jplayer

```
jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "/wp-content/themes/casaluna/music/01_Yari.mp3",
        oga: "/wp-content/themes/casaluna/music/01_Yari.ogg"
        }).jPlayer("play");
        [...]
```

Hi, where the event 'play' is triggered, I want to add a reference to function. 
(which will check if on home page)

Where, and how do I break this segment apart, to add a new function?

Comment: you should accept answers from your previous questions if you want people to bother answer your new ones

Comment: @Michel Joanisse: I would like to second JMax's comment. The only rewards we receive for answering your questions is your gratitude and the prestige of reward points. With a track record of unaccepted questions such as yours, there is little incentive for us to participate.

Comment: Hi to both @JMax and @George Cummins - I agree entirely, problem is, because of my low rank, it does not allow me to rate until I am at a certain level ... I've tried on every post I've written, making it a priority to respond, and be active to thread. 

Any advice / suggestions to get around this?

Comment: Ahh, embarassing. I never saw the 'checkmark' below the 'vote up'. (which is what I'd been trying to do, not allowing me until I have 15 reputation.) - @all my apologies, moving forward will be much more  responsive.

Comment: @Michel Joanisse: Thanks for your reply. You can accept questions regardless of rank. For example, on the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732176/php-conditional-statement-not-equal-to-operator, you can click the white check that appears under @Phoenix's answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Michel: Ah, you found it! Great news.

Comment: @George Cummins thanks for the wake up call. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-type), you can attach a handler to the play event like this:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) { // Add a listener to report the time play began
  // Get the pathname and homepage values in a manner suitable to your
  // application before the following check.
  if ( pathname != homepage ) {
      return false;
  }
});
```

If you need to unbind your function, you can do it like this:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").unbind($.jPlayer.event.play); // Remove all play event listeners
```

You can insert this code anywhere in your jQuery onload function (`$(function() {...});`) to attach the handler.

Comment: hmm, I don't necessarily want that play event to run, the function I want to add is a check on 'pathname', (If on home page, run 'play' event. Else, do nothing.)

Comment: @Michel Joanisse: I think you can do that with this structure by adding a `return false` to cancel the event. I'll edit the answer to include this.

Comment: Although, I think there is potential for a bad user experience here. Do you want your users to click on the object on the non-homepages and get no response?

Comment: Well I have a function which calls on jplayer elsewhere in script.
Being disabled during window load, there is a click event, that triggers play event.

Comment: @George Cummins - great, almost there .. My problem now, this function is evidently being triggered for each click event. How do I limit strictly to firing function on first page load?

Comment: @Michel Joanisse: You can unbind the event after it has been used once. In your function, add the call to unbind() that I referenced before.

Comment: @Michel Joanisse: I am glad it is working, and happy to help. Enjoy!